# MS bot - Web Chat welcome message & auto start conversation

Tags: botframework

I want to add a welcome message to my MS bot, with Web chat platform, a message that will appear right after the Iframe is opened. 
How can I do that?

something like : 
[image]

Thanks!

EDIT : I found [this](http://www.davidezordan.net/blog/?p=8119) solution, but I can't find where is the activities handler located..

Thanks for helping..

Comment: C# or node? In any case this is a duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

Inside your MessagesController.cs you will find the code to handle Activity types.  This is the way we recommend to send a welcome message:

```
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            IConversationUpdateActivity iConversationUpdated = message as IConversationUpdateActivity;
            if (iConversationUpdated != null)
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

                foreach (var member in iConversationUpdated.MembersAdded ?? System.Array.Empty<ChannelAccount>())
                {
                    // if the bot is added, then
                    if (member.Id == iConversationUpdated.Recipient.Id)
                    {

                        var reply = ((Activity)iConversationUpdated).CreateReply(
                            $"Hi! I'm Botty McBotface. I generally can do stuff, but can also do things.");
                        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Another duplicate, please do a quick search for older answers before creating a new answer. It helps a lot to organize the forum.

Comment: I did a couple searches on this one because I swore I had answered it before didn't find it.